# Function that copies an array and modifies its elements

Tags: c, arrays

I was asked to define a function `array_ncopy()` that takes in three arguments:

- `int *ptr` represents a pointer to an array of integers
- `int array` represents the size of the array
- `int n` represents an integer

and that copies the elements of the array pointed at by `*ptr` to another list. However all the elements with the index greater than `NUMBER` will be copied as `0`

#### This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUMBER 12
#define MAX  100
#define SIZE  8

void array_print(int *ptr, int array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array; i++){
        printf("Value of array[%d] is %d",i, ptr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int* array_create(int array) {
    int *t = malloc(array * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < array; i++) {
        t[i] = rand() % MAX;
    }

    return t;
}

int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int array, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
        if (i >= n) {
            ptr[i] = 0;
        }
        ptr[i] = ptr[i];
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main() {
  int *t = array_create(SIZE);
  int *ptr = array_ncopy(t, SIZE, NUMBER);
  array_print(ptr, NUMBER);
  free(t);
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Take for example this array:

```
{23, 7, 4, 32, 55, 2, 78, 26}
```

#### I should get this as a result:

For NUMBER = 4:

```
Value of array[0] is 83
Value of array[1] is 86
Value of array[2] is 77
Value of array[3] is 15
```

For NUMBER = 12:

```
Value of array[0] is 83
Value of array[1] is 86
Value of array[2] is 77
Value of array[3] is 15
Value of array[4] is 93
Value of array[5] is 35
Value of array[6] is 86
Value of array[7] is 92
Value of array[8] is 0
Value of array[9] is 0
Value of array[10] is 0
Value of array[11] is 0
```

#### Instead I get this output:

FOR NUMBER = 12

```
Value of array[0] is 83
Value of array[1] is 86
Value of array[2] is 77
Value of array[3] is 15
Value of array[4] is 93
Value of array[5] is 35
Value of array[6] is 86
Value of array[7] is 92
Value of array[8] is 0
Value of array[9] is 0
Value of array[10] is 4113
Value of array[11] is 0
```

Could someone correct my code so that it outputs the right thing.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < n; i++)` -> `for (int i = 0; i < array; i++)`. BTW, `ptr[i] = ptr[i];` is a no-op.

Comment: `ptr[i] = ptr[i]` doesn't really copy anything. And what is the pointer returned by `array_ncopy`? I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your code.

Comment: how do I make it copy the elements of the pointed list? The pointer returned by `array_ncopy` should be the new modified list?

Comment: You probably want a `malloc` somewhere in your `array_ncopy` function

Comment: The creaste function must create an array of MAX(SIZE,NUMBER). Currently it does not.

Comment: `if (i >= n)` will never be true because the for loop goes to `i<n`.

Comment: It should copy to _another_ list. You copy to the _same_ list (array).

Comment: The way you've implemented it, the function is modifying the array (passed as  `ptr`) in place.   In other words, it modifies the array passed, and doesn't create a copy.    If you intend that the array passed in is unmodified, and a copy (of sorts) is returned, you need to create a copy and return it - while ensuring the copy still exists after the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the specification, the copy function should be:

```
int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int array, int number)
{
    int *new_array= malloc(array*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i < array; i++){
        if (i >= number) {
            new_array[i] = 0;
        }
        else new_array[i] = ptr[i];
    }
    return new_array;
}
```

This copies the element to a new array (as specified). The array size is the same size as the old array (as implicitly specified). All elements from the old array whose index is `<= number` are copied and elements greater than this are set to zero. If `number >= array` then no elements are set to zero (as implicitly specified).

Comment: Your code makes complete sense, however I get the same output? Why does this print 4113 instead of 0 `Value of array[10] is 4113`

Comment: @MisterTusk - since your test case passes a value of `number` that exceeds `array`, none of the elements returned will differ from those passed.   In other words, `new_array[i] = 0` will never be executed for any element.   Pass those two arguments in opposite order if you want a visible change.

Answer (score 0):

This is what compiler warnings are for:

```
++ clang -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic-errors prg.c
prg.c:23:32: warning: unused parameter 'array' [-Wunused-parameter]
int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int array, int n) {
                               ^
1 warning generated.
```

You are not using the variable array at all. Do:

```
for (int i=0; i < array; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are a couple of really confusing and sometimes wrong things, i will try to go through them one by one to make it a bit clearer.

```
#define NUMBER 12 
#define MAX  100
#define SIZE 8
```

here NUMBER > SIZE; Which means your array will never reach the upper_bound.

```
    int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int array, int n)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        if (i >= n) {
            ptr[i] = 0;
        }
        ptr[i] = ptr[i];
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

`for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` - here you are looping till n(upper bound) and not the array size is reached.

This `ptr[i] = ptr[i];` doesnt copy the value to another array, but simply assigns the value to the same array again. Instead, you have to create an array `int *cpy = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));` and then assign the values to it like so:

```
    int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int length, int upperBound) // ptr = first array
    {    
int *cpy = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int)); // create copy array
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (i >= upperBound) 
                cpy[i] = 0; 
            else
            cpy[i] = ptr[i]; // copy to array if i < upperBound
        }
        return cpy;
    }
```

Aside from that:

Your naming scheme is pretty unclear in pretty much all function declarations(the names are fine, but your variable names could be more descriptive).
It is kinda hard to really know at first glance what `int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int array, int n)` array(since its an int and not a ptr) and or n might mean here. So i would suggest to change it to `array_ncopy(int *ptr, int length, int upperBound)`

**Below you can find your program in a more idiomatic way(and working)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define UPPER_BOUND 8
    #define MAX  100
    #define SIZE  12

void array_print(int *ptr, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("Value of array[%d] is %d", i, ptr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int* array_create(int length) {
    int *t = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        t[i] = rand() % MAX;
    }

    return t;
}

    int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int length, int upperBound)
    {    
int *cpy = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (i >= upperBound)
                cpy[i] = 0;
            else
            cpy[i] = ptr[i];
        }
        return cpy;
    }

    int main()
 {
    int *t = array_create(SIZE);
    int *cpy = array_ncopy(t, SIZE, UPPER_BOUND);
    array_print(cpy, SIZE);
    free(t);
    free(cpy);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
int *array_ncopy(int *ptr, unsigned int size, unsigned int number)
{
    // create a zero-filled array the same size
    int *newArray = calloc( size, sizeof( *newArray ) );

    // error checking - ALWAYS do error checking!
    if ( !newArray )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    // copy the first "number" elements to the new array
    // making sure to limit the max amount copied
    number = MIN( number, size );
    memcpy( newArray, ptr, number * sizeof( *newArray ) );
    return( newArray );
}
```

Also, using signed `int` to represent the number of elements in an array is nonsensical and could lead to some strange bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
int* array_ncopy(int *ptr, int array, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i < array; i++){
        if (i >= n) {
            ptr[i] = 0;
        }
        ptr[i] = ptr[i];
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Good luck

Comment: `ptr[i] = ptr[i];` is nonsense and overwrites `ptr[i]= 0;`.